# C++ single runtime condition using patching

Tags: c++, gcc, runtime, patch

I'm writing logs for my application using `boost::log`. I can pass environment variable to chose the logging level as follow:

```
LOG_LEVEL=3 ./my_app
```

Each time I use `LOG_INFO` or `LOG_TRACE` the macro is extended into a condition which check the selected log level and if it match it actually print the log. Otherwise nothing happen.

I'm currently writing my own logging library based on `boost::log` to add my needs. I see no reason to check the log level each time and I would like to patch the function after the first if to skip the check next time. For example:

I would wrap the `LOG_INFO` macro in my own function. The first thing in this function is to check the selected log level. If the level doesn't match I would replace the beginning of the function with `ret`. In this way I won't check this condition again.

1. How can I make such logic using gcc on Linux? I don't know where to start.
2. The compiler can inline my functions, even if it's in another cc file during the linkage. If he does that (and he will) my `ret` opcode will ruin the whole application. Any suggestions what I can do?

Thank you

Comment: Given the highly internal paralllization and pipelining of modern CPUs, I sincerely doubt that this kind of optimization will produce any measurable difference, whatsoever. The only suggestion here is to forget the whole thing and move on to something more productive. Furthermore, it is highly likely that the code segment is in a protected read-only memory segment, and this kind of patching won't work anyway.